# Python: Max date for each month from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a list that contains date and the list looks like as follow:

```
list = ['2020-04-05',
 '2020-04-12',
 '2020-04-19',
 '2020-04-26',
 '2020-05-03',
 '2020-05-10',
 '2020-05-17',
 '2020-05-24',
 '2020-05-31',
 '2020-06-07',
 '2020-06-14',
 '2020-06-21',
 '2020-06-28',
 '2020-07-05',
 '2020-07-12',
 '2020-07-19',
 '2020-07-26',
 '2020-08-02',
 '2020-08-09',
 '2020-08-16',
 '2020-08-23',
 '2020-08-30',
 '2020-09-06',
 '2020-09-20',
 '2020-09-13']
```

I want to extract the highest date of each month from the list. My desired output looks like as follow:

```
Desired list = ['2020-04-26','2020-05-31','2020-06-28','2020-07-26','2020-08-30','2020-09-20']
```

I tried to find the max date of the month using `Max()` but it gave overall max date from the list. Is there any way of finding max date of each month from the list.

Comment: Here's the most terse solution I could come up with (uses itertools.groupby and datetime.datetime).
`[list(g)[-1] for _, g in groupby(l, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[:-3], '%Y-%m'))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(l))
new_list = s.groupby(s.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')).max().tolist()
new_list
[Timestamp('2020-04-26 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-05-31 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-07-26 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-08-30 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-09-20 00:00:00')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may

- convert each string date to a `date` object using `date.fromisoformat`
- group the values by month
- for each month retrieve the max
- convert back to `string`

```
from datetime import date
from itertools import groupby
from operator import methodcaller

dates = map(date.fromisoformat, values)
dates_pre_month = groupby(sorted(dates, key=lambda x: x.month), key=lambda x: x.month)

max_per_month = (max(month_values) for month, month_values in dates_pre_month)
max_per_month = list(map(methodcaller("isoformat"), max_per_month))
```

Comment: Nice solution! 

Suggestion to sort by the complete date instead of date.month to avoid grouping the same month in different years.

sorted(dates, key=lambda x: x)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
dates = ['2020-04-05',
         '2020-04-12',
         '2020-04-19',
         '2020-04-26',
         '2020-05-03',
         '2020-05-10',
         '2020-05-17',
         '2020-05-24',
         '2020-05-31',
         '2020-06-07',
         '2020-06-14',
         '2020-06-21',
         '2020-06-28',
         '2020-07-05',
         '2020-07-12',
         '2020-07-19',
         '2020-07-26',
         '2020-08-02',
         '2020-08-09',
         '2020-08-16',
         '2020-08-23',
         '2020-08-30',
         '2020-09-06',
         '2020-09-20',
         '2020-09-13']


dct = {date.rsplit('-', 1)[0]: [] for date in dates} # Dict with keys as all the dates without the day number, and values as empty lists
for date in dates:
    y, m, d = date.split('-')
    dct[f'{y}-{m}'].append(int(d)) # Add all the days from the months into the empty lists
        
print([f'{ym}-{max(dct[ym])}' for ym in dct]) # Concat the year and months with the greatest date
```

Output:

```
['2020-04-26', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-28', '2020-07-26', '2020-08-30', '2020-09-20']
```